# Loading MAPS into a LIST - overwriting values

Tags: java, arrays, list

The code below is taking a string (that happens to be JSON) - converting it to a JSONObject and then iterating through the data.
The JSON has a schema(column) and data. My end goal is to have each of the items linked and then put into the map.

This works perfectly when each item is distinct, like the following :

```
String jsonSTR = "{\"schema\":[\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\"],\"data\":[[\"banana\",\"1\",face],[\"orange\",\"2\",\"foot\"],[\"apple\",\"3\",\"hand\"]]}";
```

Output

```
{banana=col1, orange=col1, 1=col2, apple=col1, face=col3, 2=col2, 3=col2, foot=col3, hand=col3}
```

But the second duplicates are introduced (that is included in the code below) I end up overwriting values. I tried switching the values for the input into the list, but the same issue exists.

I'm either using the wrong containers to hold this data, or I am using them incorrectly. I thought LISTS could hole duplicates.

Here's my current code :

```
import org.json.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> schemaList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> allData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        Map<String,Object> partData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String jsonSTR = "{\"schema\":[\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\"],\"data\":[[\"banana\",\"orange\",2],[\"face\",\"arm\",\"eye\"],[\"yes\",\"no\",\"no\"]]}";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonSTR);


        //Getting schema
        JSONArray schema = jsonObj.getJSONArray("schema");
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.length(); i++)
        {
            schemaList.add(schema.get(i).toString());
        }

        //Getting data
        JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONArray row = data.getJSONArray(j);
            for (int k = 0; k < row.length(); k++)
            {
                partData.put(schema.get(k).toString(),row.get(k));
                allData.add(partData);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(allData.get(0));
        System.out.println(allData.get(1));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data has to be in the map with the key, then no data can be repeated in any column, so it is not the best solution.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> toMap(String jsonSTR) {

    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonSTR);

    JSONArray schema = jsonObj.getJSONArray("schema");
    JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < schema.length(); i++) {

        String key = schema.get(i).toString();
        result.put(key, new ArrayList<>());

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++)
            result.get(key).add(((JSONArray)data.get(j)).get(i).toString());

    }
    return result;
}
```

In:
"{\"schema\":[\"col1\",\"col2\",\"col3\",\"col4\"],\"data\":[[\"banana\",\"1\",\"face\",\"black\"],[\"orange\",\"2\",\"foot\",\"red\"],[\"apple\",\"3\",\"hand\",\"yellow\"]]}"

Out:
{col4=[black, red, yellow], col2=[1, 2, 3], col3=[face, foot, hand], col1=[banana, orange, apple]}

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: That would work! But I actually found my main issue! The map I created was the same reference each time. I needed to instantiate it. So I just added partData = new HashMap<>(); and everything worked out great!